# Is the model or cost function that shapes these lines?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a question about cost functions in Machine Learning and their graphs. For instance, look at the following images. What function shapes them, the cost function or the model? I though was the cost function, like MSE in the first image. The second image I have no idea what function has that shape. All this is very confusing to me because in the book "Hands on Machine Learning... 2nd Edition" page 122 is written:

> Fortunately, the MSE cost function for a Linear Regression model happens to be a convex function...

and

> This implies that there are no local minima, just one global minimum.

What I don't understand is why MSE is convex only with Linear Regression model if it is quadratic? I mean, I believe that function always will have that "bowl" shape because it is quadratic. Or maybe not always because if was like that would be easy to choose MSE for any model and I would find the global minimum always since the main goal in a machine learning process is minimize the value of the cost function.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean when you say the model? Because, in my opinion, your model is cost function. Regarding the convexity of MSE which can be considered a separate question on its own,  I recommend you search google. You will find a good explanation.  The second graph, can be achieved **from the cost function** of **a NN model** where non-linearity exists because of stacking several layers of linear function together.

Comment: This is a good question, but it is not about programming; it would be a better fit for stats.SE or datascience.SE.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `python` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why MSE is convex only with Linear Regression model if it is quadratic? I mean, I believe that function always will have that "bowl" shape because it is quadratic.

You're right.

- The MSE cost function will be always convex **over ***θ*****.
- It will also be always convex **over ***x*** if a model, ***θ = f(x)***, is linear**.
- It could be, however, non-convex **over ***x*** if a model is non-linear**.

For example, if a model is *θ = x<sup>2</sup>*

*MSE(θ) = √(θ' - θ)<sup>2</sup> = √(θ' - x<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup>*

will have two global minima, one at *x = √|θ'|* and the other at *x = -√|θ'|*. (Kind of "w" shape rather than "bowl" shape.)

But over the axis of *θ*, there is only one global minimum at *θ = θ'*.